# Attempt to index a nil value (local 'result')

Tags: lua

I'm working on a phone script for Fivem when a player joins the counsel gets this error. "SCRIPT ERROR: @phone/server/server.lua:64: attempt to index a nil value (local 'result')

> handler (@phone/server/server.lua:581)"

I am going complete blank on a way to fix this error. Any would-be greatly appreciated.

code from line 64

```
function getNumberPhone(identifier)
  local result = MySQL.Sync.fetchAll("SELECT users.phone_number FROM users WHERE users.identifier = @identifier", {
      ['@identifier'] = identifier
  })
  if result[1] ~= nil then
      return result[1].phone_number
  end
  return nil
```

code from line 581

```
AddEventHandler('Phone:allUpdate', function()
    local sourcePlayer = tonumber(source)
    local identifier = getPlayerID(source)
    local num = getNumberPhone(identifier)
    TriggerClientEvent("Phone:myPhoneNumber", sourcePlayer, num)
    TriggerClientEvent("Phone:contactList", sourcePlayer, getContacts(identifier))
    TriggerClientEvent("Phone:allMessage", sourcePlayer, getMessages(identifier))
    TriggerClientEvent('Phone:getBourse', sourcePlayer, getBourse())
    sendHistoriqueCall(sourcePlayer, num)
end)
```

Comment: I can't tell very well from what you've given me, but it looks like a function call in `AddEventHandler ` (probably `getNumberPhone`?) triggers a function which leads you to line 64. Whatever is in that function, `result` is definitely `nil`. I know this because your error says "attempt to index a nil value (local 'result')"

Comment: Add there entire code block leading to line 64 and I might be able to help

Comment: updated it. thought I had the whole block my bad.

Comment: it looks like the error should be occurring at "if result[1]" not "return result[1].phone_number". Is this correct?

Comment: That is right..

Comment: I think your problem is that you there are no results for your SQL request, and so `result` is nil. If you then try to access the key "1" on result when it's nil, will will throw the "attempt to index a nil value" error.

Comment: I'll add an answer to make it safe. One second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `result ~= nil and` to your if statement the error should go away.

```
function getNumberPhone(identifier)
  local result = MySQL.Sync.fetchAll("SELECT users.phone_number FROM users WHERE users.identifier = @identifier", {
      ['@identifier'] = identifier
  })
  if result ~= nil and result[1] ~= nil then
      return result[1].phone_number
  end
  return nil
```

The problem is that sometimes your SQL query is returning `nil`, which sets `result` to `nil`. Then you try to access `1` on `result`, which is `nil`, so it throws the error "attempt to index a nil value".

To fix this, just make sure that `result` isn't `nil` before attempting to lookup a key on it.

Comment: Thank you will check this when I sit back down at my PC. Would you be willing to help me with 1 other error as well?

Comment: @Nix Sure! Is it related to this bug?

Comment: Yes it is one more came up in another version of the phone script.

Comment: @Nix wherever you post it, just tag my username in a comment so I see it